# How can I remove a QListWidgetItem from a QListWidget and refresh the display?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, pyside

I am using a QListWidget to display a list of QListWidgetItem

This list is read from a file. When I close the file, I want to empty the list.

I did this method on my :

```
class QuestionsList(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QuestionsList, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setProperty("showDropIndicator", False)
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        self.quiz = None

    def loadQuiz(self, quiz):
        self.quiz = quiz

        self.flush()

        if quiz is not None:

            i = 1
            for question in quiz.questions_list:
                self.addItem(QuestionItem(i, question, self))
                i += 1


    def flush(self):
        for item in [self.item(i) for i in xrange(self.count())]:
            print unicode(item.text())
            self.removeItemWidget(item)
            del item
```

The loadQuiz method works, the flush method print the text of each item but nor removeItemWidget method nor del item works to empty the list.

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why wont use clear method on QListWidget ?

Comment: Actually it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205537/897968), but I came across this question to find a way to delete **the selected** item(s).

This can be done like so:

```
def removeSelected(self):
    for item in self.selectedItems():
        self.takeItem(self.row(item))
```

Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, removeItemWidget doesn't work for this purpose.

Here is my solution

```
def flush(self):
    while self.count() > 0:
        self.takeItem(0)
```

The method takeItem(0) works like a pop() in a Stack and takeItem(count()-1) like a pop() in a queue.